# Using flashvar inside actionscript

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a live streaming media platform and have a Flash interface. I need the instance string to be unique to each user profile it sits on. I have the following in my PHP.

```
var flashvars = {};
flashvars.instance =  escape('<?php $global $user; $drupaluserid = $user->uid?>');
```

The AS3 is where the string needs to be set, I have this.

```
private var INSTANCE:String = "default";
public function setInstanceName(inst:String):void{
        INSTANCE = inst;
    }
```

Not sure how to proceed before I compile the Flash app to grab the flashvar.

Answer (score 0):

Flash vars come into your Flash movie as `loaderInfo.parameters` which is an Object. In your case you would have to write

```
var instance:String = loaderInfo.parameters.instance;
```

in your Document Class or main class.

More info here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters

Comment: Kind of confused here the loaderInfo part shows as an undefined property.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you may want to use a Singleton class to be initiated in your main constructor, then Called from anywhere in your code:

https://github.com/mikatalk/AS3-goodies/blob/master/utils/FlashVarsHelper.as

```
// initialize in your Main.as doc:
FlashVarsHelper.initialize(loaderInfo.parameters.instance);
// then call it from anywhere:
FlashVarsHelper.getValueByName("instance");
```

Note that this library is not case sensitive to prevent external typo errors.